# Segmentation fault when importing smtplib after psycopg2

Tags: python, psycopg2, smtplib

Recently, I have started getting a segmentation fault when importing both smtplib and psycopg2 using python 2.6.6 on Centos 6 . It only occurs if psycopg2 is imported before smtplib.

For example, this works fine:

```
import smtplib
import psycopg2
```

This causes a segmentation fault:

```
import psycopg2
import smtplib
```

To attempt to debug, I installed faulthandler and ran this:

```
 import faulthandler
 faulthandler.enable()
 import psycopg2
 import smtplib
```

When I run this, I get the following output:

```
Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault
Current thread 0xb7714940 (most recent call first):
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 50 in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 44 in <module>
File "testpython.py", line 6 in <module>
Segmentation fault
```

This points to socket.py as the offender. I looked at line 50, and it simply imports _ssl. To further debug, I ran this:

```
import psycopg2
import _ssl
```

It also segmentation faults the same way, so the _ssl import after importing psycopg2 is the problem, but I am unsure how to correct it. I tried re-installing psycopg2, and uninstalling it and installing using pip, but the problem remains. Any help on solving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are using Python 2.6, try upgrading to see if the problem still persists.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but I can't really upgrade. Yum relies on python 2.6 , so I have to be careful and not replace 2.6. I can install 2.7 along with 2.6, but then  I would need to re-install all the modules we use everywhere, and test to ensure that all the production scripts still function correctly with  2.7. This would be a lengthy process.

Comment: Trying to troubleshoot a segmentation fault isn't exactly a quick process either. I would bet good money its longer than installing Python 2.7 in parallel and then pointing your projects to it. Its just a matter of setting up virtual environment and then installing the requirements for each project; a simple bash script could take care of it in minutes. If you configure a global pip cache, then you won't be re-downloading things again saving you yet more time. Besides, its a lot less scary than your current solution.

Answer (score 0):

A segmentation fault is not something you can correct as a Python programmer. I suggest to [report a bug in the Python library](http://bugs.python.org/).

Comment: For now, I had to grep for files with the offending import order, and just switch the order to avoid the segmentation fault. This works, but it is a little scary not knowing the root cause of the issue.

Comment: Just as an update. I recently installed python2.7 on the same server, and the same exact issue occurs when using Python 2.7.10 as well.